# Get weekly / monthly records in laravel 4.2 and 5+?

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-4.2

How do I use the created_at field to get only the records that were created last week and all the weeks of the month and monthly in laravel 4.2 and 5+ versions?

Comment: Look into `groupBy` and `whereBetween`.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch record which inserted within one week in laravel, simple example below..

```
$7days_ago_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-8 days', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));

$Tracker = Tracker::orderby('created_at', 'desc')->whereBetween( 
DB::raw('date(created_at)'), [$7days_ago_date, date('Y-m-d')] )->get();
```